# How to use obx (in flutter) for PreferredSize

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

```
...
appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(controller.isHiddenHeaderBottom.value ? 56 : 106),
          child: Column(
            children: [
...
```

`PreferredSize` is not covered to Obx.

I want to update `PreferredSize` by `isHiddenHeaderBottom` (Rx variable).

I thought wrapping the entire scaffold might be a bit wasteful.

Comment: How about? Wrapping it with Getbuilder to handle heavy load widget